Vcalendar css not importing properly
I'm having an issue with vCalendar. The date picking functions correctly, but the CSS doesn't seem to match what's shown on their website, plus some boxes look odd (the select has extra borders). I'm not quite sure what to do.
app.js:
import { setupCalendar, Calendar, DatePicker } from 'v-calendar';
//this import below does nothing
import 'v-calendar/style.css';

const app = createApp(App);

setupCalendar(app);
app.component('VCalendar', Calendar);
app.component('VDatePicker', DatePicker);

// some routing

app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');

Using the calendar:
<VDatePicker v-model="date" mode="dateTime" is24hr />

The result I expect is shown in the first image, but the result I get is shown in the second image.



I'd move off VCalendar. It hasn't seen activity from it's maintainer in almost a year. Regardless, the stylesheet import clearly is working for the most part, because there's still many styles obviously being applied. Try seeing what it looks like without the import statement to see what I mean... To get it looking the way you want, the solution is to add your own CSS. Here's a github issue with a workaround for fixing the top part.  To improve the timepicker it looks like you just need .vc-base-select > select { border: none; }

@yoduh thanks for the fix/workaround. what you recommend then instead of VCalendar
